# Remove the buttons in a google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to ask if your able to remove the other buttons in a google map.Is it possible? How to remove the buttons like the view full screen button, the Google button, the other buttons. Please see attach image for reference. I wanted to remove the buttons that are encircled. [image]
This is my code.

```
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.8797, 121.7740),
          zoom: 7
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl('phpsqlajax_genxml.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var image = markerElem.getAttribute('image');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
              var text = document.createElement('text');
              text.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(text);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                icon: 'images.png',
                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }

      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the controls individually like this.

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.8797, 121.7740),
        zoom: 7,
        scaleControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: false
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in the funtion `initMap()` add `disableDefaultUI: true`

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.8797, 121.7740),
    zoom: 7,
    disableDefaultUI: true
});
```

more info in [Disabling the default UI](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-disableUI)

Doesn't remove the google button on the bottom though.

Comment: Oh thanks @Fenrir but is it available to remove other buttons, not all buttons?

Comment: you're missing a comma after `zoom: 7`

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `disableDefaultUI: true` as suggested by Fenrir, however removing of logo is prohibited as per [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions)

> **No removing, obscuring, or altering terms of service, links, or
>   proprietary rights notices**. You will not: remove, obscure, or alter
>   any Google terms of service or any links to or notices of those terms,
>   or any copyright, trademark, or other proprietary rights notices; or
>   falsify or delete any author attributions, legal notices, or other
>   labels of the origin or source of material.